# function name(e) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, event-handling

As a complete Javascript novice I'm challenged by some simple concentps.

When I'm doing my javascript I'll often see stuff like this

```
function name(e) {

    if(e.KeyCode) { 
        ....
    }
}
```

What does doing this accomplish? What's the `e` all about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like the function is to be called by the browser (or whatever) when firing a specific event (in this case I guess it's keyboard related; e stands for event or event data).

So once fired, the caller will pass the event structure as a parameter (copied to e). JavaScript won't define any local/global variables just for the one specific call so KeyCode won't be defined but e contains that variable.

Answer (score 5):

`e` here is the event. Note that the letter `e` isn't important, it's just a paramater name. You could call it anything, but `e` is standard and makes it obvious to other people reading your code.

example:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="doSomething(event)"/>

function doSomething(e) {
    alert('you pressed key:' + e.keyCode);
}
```

So `e.keyCode` is telling you which key was pressed.

Comment: oops thanks Tim. I just copied it from the OP. Corrected now :)

Answer (score 1):

The `e` is the event object passed to the function in most cases, it's checking the `keyCode` property of the event object that was passed in.

For example in Firefox you can do this:

```
document.onclick = myFunction;
function myFunction(e) {
  //e is the click event object
  //e.keyCode, e.target, etc.
}
```

This works because by default, it passes the event to the handler as the first argument.  For your example does this make it clearer?

```
function name(someObject) { //or event, or any name works
  if(someObject.keyCode) {
```

Comment: You'll need the nasty `e = e || window.event` thing here for IE.

Answer (score 1):

`KeyCode` is undefined (by itself). It is a property or attribute of `e`, so you must call it with `e.KeyCode`. `e` is (presumably) an event *object*. Maybe you should brush up on [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)?

Comment: @Tim: Just wrote it the way he had it. C# conventions start with a cap letter... forgot what JS does.

Answer (score 0):

"e" is a parameter - an event object - passed to the function when it's called.

Answer (score 0):

It is an event object. Read about [Events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

Answer (score 0):

e = shorthand variable name for the event that gets passed into the function.